# How to reduce the processing time of Sumproduct?

Tags: vba, excel

Introduction: I have a spreadsheet that is populated every daily based on the values of another worksheet. Currently the cells are being populated using a SUMPRODUCT formula. This is a piece of a larger process in which I intend to automate using VBA.

Formula example:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(((TEXT(crstage!$W$3:$W$23625,"###")=TEXT(credits!$A4,"###"))*(crstage!$X$3:$X$23625)*(TEXT(B$3,"yymmdd")=LEFT(crstage!$F$3:$F$23625,6))))
```

Problem: The processing time for the SUMPRODUCT formula is too long for my current needs. The numbers for previous days are subject to change therefore I have to keep the SUMPRODUCT formula in every applicable cell.

Worksheets: I have two worksheets, "credits" and "crstage". I have provided mock versions of the credit and crstage worksheets. The worksheets are significantly larger.

Credits: Total Daily credits for a given day. This worksheet is overwritten every day with a new set of data. This new set of data can change the amounts of the previous day.

[image]

crstage: A running total of credits.
[image]

Question: Utilizing VBA how can I avoid lengthy processing time?

Comment: Apart from the main question is it intentional that crstage!$X$2:$X$23625 starts from 2 row and other references from 3rd?

Comment: do you really have 23,000+ lines of data?  Is that stagnate, or does it change regularly?

Comment: @TomJohnRiddle That was not intentional and I have since updated the formula.

Comment: @ScottCraner the length of the worksheet varies but it generally does not get that large.

Comment: Then lessen the number of rows it is is iterating to the actual data.  For each additional row the sumproduct is doing multiple calculations as it created the arrays against which it iterates.  It may not seem like much but a couple hundred lines is close to a million extra calculations.

Comment: Agree with Scott, but could you not use a pivot table?

Comment: @SJR Correct me if I am wrong butt I believe that a pivot table lacks the functionality that I need. I have to sum based on a code and a date and then copy that information to a corresponding cell. This would require me to constantly change the pivot tables values and then I would still have to copy the data.

Comment: Think you can do that with a PT. Someone here will know for sure but I think PTs are probably quicker than formulae and you can automate the lot with code. I'd at least give it a try.

Comment: Using helper columns for the first TEXT part and the last LEFT part would probably speed things up and allow you to use SUMIFS which should be a little faster. It would also simplify using a pivot table and some GETPIVOTDATA formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make it work like how I have it setup in my screenshot below? See the formula bar for the key formula.

[image]

Formula in B3 is =DATE("20"&LEFT(A3,2), MID(A3,3,2), MID(A3,5,2))

Edit: Pivot Table solution can be seen in image below:

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate on where the values in the credit column come from? I'm looking for the sum of each "code" for a given day. From there I would like to move it to the corresponding day in the credit worksheet.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the situation before. I see what you're looking for now. Can you try out the new situation in my answer? I edited it with a new screenshot and formula. Uses a SUMIFS instead of a SUMPRODUCT. I would still recommend looking into Excel tables though, which I haven't done in my screenshot, just because it allow you to get these formulas to work no matter how many rows are in the table. I'm guessing you're doing FIND & REPLACES to edit your formulas each day to adjust to the right amount of rows? You can get around that, but maybe a topic for another post :D.

Comment: I just confirmed your method works and it does decrease the processing time. Going forward i'll have to think of a way to implement this for each cell on the credit sheet using VBA. Thank you for the help!

Comment: If you're going to try to automate the creation of new days in the credit worksheet, then at that point you probably want to change your credit worksheet into a PivotTable. It'll just make things easier. I've edit my answer with another screenshot showing how you could VERY easily setup that PivotTable. As you add new days to the crstage worksheet, the PivotTable would automatically update. And it would all perform extremely quickly.